# Code runs one time and stops, doesn't loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open('C:/Users/Sikander/Desktop/bradpitt.html')
for line in f.readlines():
    p = line.partition('<a href="http://')
    url = p[2].partition('">')
    l = p[1] + url[0] + url[1]
    print(l)
    line = p[2]
```

This is my code, this code runs one time and stops.But I want my code to run again until line == ' '. How can I do it? I'm printing links from a webpage. My code gets the first link and doesn't get the other links. If a page has 4 links it will only print first link and stops and other 3 links are not printed.

What should I do?

Comment: Please indent your code as it actually appears; that might be the problem, but since you don't show your actual indentation, its impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the html page is just one huge line.
May be you can loop through it with something like:

```
f = open('C:/Users/Sikander/Desktop/bradpitt.html')
text = f.read()
while('<a href="http://' in text):
    #process it
    text = text[text.index('<a href="http://')+16:]
```

I would suggest you to use beautiful soup module to collect all the links in the webpage.

Comment: this would be easy to verify with `print(text.count('<a href="http://'), text.count("\n"))`, if the first number is more then 1 and the second number is 0 or 1, then this is the OP's problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indent the subsequent lines that should be in the loop.

It might be easier to see why your code didn't do what you expected in a script rather than in console.  Sometimes the presence of the `>>>` can obscure indentation

```python
f = open('C:/Users/Sikander/Desktop/bradpitt.html')
for line in f.readlines():
p = line.partition('<a href="http://')
url = p[2].partition('">')
l = p[1] + url[0] + url[1]
print(l)
line = p[2]
```

I'm guessing what you wanted is something like this:

```python
f = open('C:/Users/Sikander/Desktop/bradpitt.html')
for line in f.readlines():
    head, sep, tail = line.partition('<a href="http://')
    urlhead, urlsep, urltail = tail.partition('">')
    l = sep + head + urltail
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment  yet...

I am going to add on to @wtpoo. I think this is the case, you won't always get a return carriage in an html document. So `readline()` is working as intended.

The only addition I would add is to account for `https://`